# Why the player hasn't show after hidden? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I create the player and the button on my stack.The button is handle the player for hide or show.

When I open stack the player has show normally.After I touch the button for hide and show again.The player has problem to picture below.

Before hide:

[image]

After hide:

[image]

What's happen ?

Answer (score 1):

From the style of the player, it looks like you are running a DP (developer preview) version of LiveCode 6.7. It would seem you have discovered a bug as I can replicate this issue.

Our release cycle is as follows

-DP =  developer preview
-RC = release candidate
-GM (Stable) = golden master

As this is the case, could you please file a report on this issue with our Quality Control Team at the following site-

http://quality.runrev.com

To resolve the issue for now (for non-retina macs), please download the most stable version of LiveCode which is currently 6.6.1. You will be able to access this from either your store account our our main downloads portal here-

http://downloads.livecode.com/livecode

Kind Regards,

Neil Roger

RunRev Support Team ~ http://www.runrev.com

Comment: Thank you for answer.But I'm use retina display.

Comment: Hi KemChat, Thank you for submitting the report 12481. Our dev team have managed to track down the issue and it will be fixed in the next release of LiveCode 6.7